# Не открывается .xlsx в datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, oledb

Возникла проблема с WPF: в приложении у меня при нажатии кнопки должен открыться файл с расширением .xlsx и его содержимое перенестись в DataGrid, что не происходит, всё так  пустым и остаётся.

```
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb) |*.xml; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 3;

            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";

            Nullable<bool> result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                string pathName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                DataTable tbContainer = new DataTable();
                string strConn = string.Empty;
                string sheetName = fileName;

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathName);
                if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
                string extension = file.Extension;
                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls":
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx":
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                    default:
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                }
                OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}$]", sheetName), cnnxls);
                oda.Fill(tbContainer);

                gridStudents.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = tbContainer });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуй явно зарефрешить свой DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы указываете в запросе имя файла, а нужно - имя листа
2. Вы игнорируете все исключения, поэтому вы не можете даже увидеть сообщение об ошибке

Вывести содержимое первого листа можно так:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb) |*.xml; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 3;

openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";

Nullable<bool> result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    string pathName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    DataTable tbContainer = new DataTable();
    string strConn = string.Empty;                    
    string sheetName;

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathName);
    if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
    string extension = file.Extension;
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls":
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
            break;
        default:
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
            break;
    }
    OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
    using (cnnxls)
    {
        cnnxls.Open();

        DataTable dtSchema = cnnxls.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        sheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME");                        

        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}]", sheetName), cnnxls);
        oda.Fill(tbContainer);
    }

    grid1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = tbContainer });
}
```